# Migrating to GA4. Will my analytics.js based UA-XXXXX code still work?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I have created a GA4 account for every UA account we were tracking. The actual UA-XXXX code is analytics.js based in the source code. After July 1, 2023 would I still continue receiving data on the new linked GA4 accounts?
Or should we update the core code base with the new G-XXXXX code with the gtag.js snippet? or can we do that migration slowly at a later time?

I have already linked the GA4 with my old UA and its recording data at the moment.

Comment: You should have started migrating a year ago you are going to be very busy this month depending of course on how complicated you system is

Comment: Same question, will analytics.js keep working? or we have to change all the code to use gtag?